Why does SSMS generate many tilde files when saving a SQL file?
I'm using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 20.1 to edit a file containing SQL commands.  The file itself, sqlCommands.sql, is being provided via a WebDAV server that we've written.  If we make an edit to the file in SSMS and save it, the save succeeds, but only after writing about 20 files with random-looking names ending in a tilde (~), e.g., "puq2tvqq.ms1~".

If I monitor the web traffic with WireShark, I can see that there are many WebDAV requests being made.

Why are these 0-length files being created, i.e., what is their purpose?  Is there a way to avoid them, e.g., an SSMS setting?  BTW, I haven't noticed this behavior while editing the same file with other editors.
UPDATE: It looks like our server is not successfully handling the PUT command for the tilde files.  I'm wondering if maybe SSMS has retry logic such that when the PUT fails, it tries ~20 times more.  It's odd though.  Is the tilde file some kind of lock file?  Does SSMS try to save a lock file 20 times, then says, the heck with this I'm going to save it anyway?

have you ever noticed that if you open a number of queries in SSMS, and then kill its process, that on next open it asks if you want to restore the unsaved queries? The behavior is similar to working with MS Office files. I think you will find that those files were not always empty, but became empty after a successful save.

@FrankThomas - those files weren't present in the directory until I began to save.

from your wireshark capture, you are PUTting those files, meaning they existed on your local system prior to PUTting the sqlcommands.sql file. if you look at the files on your local system prior to save, do they have content?

@FrankThomas - I didn't see any temp files being created in C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp.  Is there somewhere else I should look?

The tilde files are supposed to be temporary and hidden - most text editors use them to make sure the entire file is saved before removing the old copy. It's likely that something interrupts the save process -> SSMS retries the save without cleaning up -> you are left with multiple temp files.
Many different things can cause that kind of behavior. Certain kinds of file locks, timeout settings, network issues, etc. In your setup, with what looks like SSMS > Windows > Storage explorer > WebDAV mount > S3(?), there's a lot that could go wrong.
As a starting point, you should look at the webdav responses from the server in wireshark as well, and make sure those PUTs actually succeed, as well as any delete requests for the temp files.

Yes, the PUTs of the tilde files are failing. Unfortunately, I see no DELETEs for the temp files being sent.  I'm thinking/hoping that I can fix the problem with the failed PUTs; otherwise, it's a mess.

Building on top of @Cpt.Whale's answer, here's what I think is happening:

SSMS generates a random file name ending with a tilde, and makes a PUT request for the tilde file
The StorageExplorer successfully saves the tilde file; HOWEVER, further processing results in StorageExplorer returning a 500 response (server error)
SSMS gets the 500 response, assumes the tilde file hasn't been written so doesn't try to delete it, and tries again (back to step 1), 19 times.

After the 19 failures, SSMS saves the SQL file anyway.
I can confirm what is happening in the web traffic and the server (StorageExplorer) processing.  I'm just guessing at the SMSS logic.
